# Having Trouble With AWS HTTPS Redirects

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, https

Sorry for the rookie question, but I was unable to find the answer when I searched.

I'm trying to learn how to use AWS, and to do so I'm setting up an online blog with my own domain name.  I purchased the domain name, set it up, and everything was working.  I was able to get to my page.

Then I wanted to add a TLS certificate, so I set that up, set up a load balancer, connected CloudFront to the load balancer, and waited for that to set up.  But when I then tried to access the page, I got an error saying that CloudFront couldn't connect to the page.

So I decided to try to start from scratch.  I deleted my CloudFront, Load Balancer, Security Certificate, and EC2 instance, started a new EC2 instance, and hooked up Route 53 to it.

But now when I try to access my domain, it still tries to redirect to HTTPS and I get an error.  Since I deleted the load balancer and Cloudfront, I can't figure out where it is trying to redirect to HTTPS.  How can I stop AWS from trying to redirect to HTTPS and instead just use HTTP?

Comment: did you try hitting your the url in safari browser? i had same issue with y website

Comment: Yes, I tried Firefox and it worked, but if I used Chrome, even on a different machine, it tried to redirect.

Comment: Once you attach a certificate to a domain and after some time you remove and try hitting the http url chrome treats it as a threat, thats why it always tries to redirect you to https

Comment: can you test the url for the issues here https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/?